# SQL-Statement provides unexpected result

Tags: html, mysql, distinct

I've the following table (mTable)

```
id  | sent                  | number    
---------------------------------------
23  | 2017-03-02 00:00:00   | 0
23  | 2017-03-04 00:00:00   | 0
45  | 2017-03-15 00:00:00   | 1.8
45  | 2017-03-17 00:00:00   | 1.9

id: integer, not unique, no primary key
sent: timestamp
number: float
```

The SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id`, number as mynum, MAX(`sent`) AS sentOn FROM `mTable` GROUP BY `id`
```

The result is:

```
id  | mynum  |  sentOn  
------------------------------------
23  | 0      | 2017-03-04 00:00:00
45  | 1.8    | 2017-03-17 00:00:00
```

The expected result would be:

```
id  | mynum  |  sentOn  
------------------------------------
23  | 0      | 2017-03-04 00:00:00
45  | 1.9    | 2017-03-17 00:00:00
```

In the second row I would expect to be the mynum(1.9) with the latest sent date(2017-03-17 00:00:00).
Instead the SQL-Query provides the mynum(1.8) from the second latest send date(2017-03-15 00:00:00).

Any hints, to solve the problem?
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is the wrong way to get the most recent value.  Here is a more appropriate way:

```
select m.*
from mtable m
where m.sent = (select max(m2.sent) from mtable m2 where m.id = m2.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `maximum` value for `mynum` as well, then you need to apply `MAX` on `mynum`, e.g.:

```
SELECT `id`, MAX(number) as mynum, MAX(`sent`) AS sentOn 
FROM `mTable` 
GROUP BY `id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Group By` Clause Which is wrong . Use Aggregation function in your `select`  then use `Group By`.. Such as Below :

```
SELECT id, MAX(number) as mynum, MAX(sent) AS sentOn 
FROM mTable
GROUP BY id
```

**This link help to about Group By Clause.**

[Helping Link For Group By](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

Comment: this group by clause is not wrong,in mysql such kind of syntax is allowed..while sql server doesn't allow this